# Unable to rdp to VM after connecting to AAD DC problems

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-active-directory, rdp, domaincontroller

I have 2 problems with azure aad and VM.

First of all, I wanted to create an azure aad with a VM running windows server 2016 R2 as my DC. I installed all the roles and features, now I created the other VM to connect it to the DC after I connected it I can't sign on using any known account.

Furthermore now it seems like the DC just is not running anymore after I restarted the pc. I tried changing the NIC to a working one but the problem remained.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddtwp.png]

Does anyone what this problem exactly is and how do I solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do based on your information. Can you please edit it a bit for clarity? In other words, 1) are you running a stand-alone DC in Azure and wanting to sync your user to Azure AD, or 2) are you using Azure AD DS, joined your server to it, or 3) are you just wanting to have a DC in Azure, in such case Azure AD does is a separate service and is not related to this? I'm not sure how your DC and Azure AD related to each other. In any case, there is this feature https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/reset-rdp you can use to reset RDP access.

Comment: @kim I am kind of a noob In this, my plan was to make a server and join it to azure AD DS, I ran AD connect and in azure it showed that the sync was succesfull, as for the link to reset rdp access i'll try it out and report back on it. Thanks

Comment: No problem! We all start somewhere :) and being brave enough to ask questions is a big thing, so no worries. But, if you want to sync users to the Azure AD from your local Active Directory (although it now runs in a VM in Azure), then you just need to install Azure AD Connect and have a VM with Active Directory Domain Services installed. In this case no need for "Azure AD Domain Services", which is a completely separate service. However, if your plan is to use "Azure AD DS", then no need to install a local domain controller, Azure AD DS will act as your domain controller.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help @kim. So I installed AD connect on the VM running on the Server AD DS, but as i understand you are saying i need to install on an other computer? Now i can not do anything until i sort this problem out of why my VM seems "dead" i restarted it without any good luck. Thanks alot for your help really appreciate it :)

Comment: Technically you can have ADDS and Azure AD Connect installed on the same server but I don't think that's a good practise. But if you are just trying out stuff, then why not, it will work. "Azure AD DS" is a cloud service that you don't install anywhere you just create it and use it, it's more of a cloud version on server ADDS, but with some limitations.

Comment: I will try it out as soon as i get my server back up, I still haven't found a solution for it. got any help?